# Free completely memory of byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I'm creating a streaming app that get byte from server continuity with this code:

```
while (true)
            {
                byte[] buffer = await _client.GetStreamOneCameraAsync();
                if (buffer.Length == 0) continue;
                SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(buffer.AsBuffer(), BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8, 1280, 960);
                //buffer = null; if I put this here, it will solve the memory leak
                //GC.Collect();
                if (softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat != BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8 ||
                    softwareBitmap.BitmapAlphaMode == BitmapAlphaMode.Straight)
                {
                    softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
                }
                _imageSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
                await _imageSource.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmap);

                // Set the source of the Image control
                image_Preview.Source = _imageSource;

            }
```

So my question is: Is it enough to clear all the memory that byte[] taken?
My next task is display that image to the UI. So maybe it will make the memory leak?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks you guys for supporting. I just realize that my memory leak problem was came out when I convert that buffer to image and display it into the UI and not dispose it. it doesn't due to the byte[]

**UPDATE 2:** I updated full of my code. Please help me to check where make the memory leak?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i explicitly clear the byte\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892732/how-do-i-explicitly-clear-the-byte)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't see the point in clearing if your next iteration will overwrite `buffer` anyway. I suspect you are trying to solve a problem that is rather caused by `// Do some stuff` than your `byte[] buffer`.

Comment: There are very few times when an explicit call to `GC.Collect()` is necessary, I'd argue that calling within your loop would create more of a performance impact than potentially not unallocating your byte array. As you are redefining `buffer` on each loop iteration, let the GC do it's job and manage the heap for you.

Comment: I have had occasional memory problems with allocating multiple large buffers in very quick succession which have been resolved by calling GC.Collect() - I believe the problems were related to memory fragmentation rather than being out of memory - see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240860/what-causes-memory-fragmentation-in-net). It may be appropriate to put any disposable objects (like SoftwareBitmap) in a using statement & move the GC-Collect() call to either the start or the end of the while loop.

Comment: The memory old byte[] taken wasn't gone. I keep tracking the processing memory chart in VS 2017 and see it increase very fast. So I think it necessary to set buffer = null here.

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy No, nulling out the variable doesn't do anything.  It's eligible for collection even without that, so long as nothing else references the array.

Comment: Please check my update in the question

Answer (score 3):

Actually I believe there is no point in setting `buffer` to `null` here.
Once your loop resets he buffer is going to be redefined anyways, and the old memory will be cleared by the automatic GarbageCollector.

If you really spot a memory leak you can try forcing garbage collection, but in this case that shouldn't be necessary. (Although it could depend on how your method goes on after the `// Do some stuff`.)

*References:*

[Whats so wrong about GC.Collect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118633/whats-so-wrong-about-using-gc-collect)
[When is it acceptable to call GC.Collect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478167/when-is-it-acceptable-to-call-gc-collect)

**Edit:**

I believe placing the SoftwareBitmap in a `using` clause to guarantee that the resources are freed, should solve your memory leak.

```
using (SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.CreateCopyFromBuffer(buffer.AsBuffer(), BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8, 1280, 960);)
{
    buffer = null;
    GC.Collect();
    if (softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat != BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8 ||
        softwareBitmap.BitmapAlphaMode == BitmapAlphaMode.Straight)
    {
        softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied);
    }
    _imageSource = new SoftwareBitmapSource();
    await _imageSource.SetBitmapAsync(softwareBitmap);

    // Set the source of the Image control
    image_Preview.Source = _imageSource;
}
```

Comment: The memory old byte[] taken wasn't gone. I keep tracking the processing memory chart in VS 2017 and see it increase very fast. So I think it necessary to set buffer = null here

Comment: I think Visual Studio offers tools to view what uses up memory sections. Can you try checking them?

Comment: Not yet. But after I set buffer = null there it stop increasing so I think i have some memory leak around

Comment: Thats weird. Normally C# would overwrite the buffer though.

Comment: I some line of code below that, I convert the buffer to image and display it. maybe it make memory leak

Comment: have you considered using the `using ()` block there? It's pretty useful to dispose stuff like images once they are no longer needed.

Comment: I think it is an amazing idea. I will try it and let you know late. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, we cannot put softwarebitmap into using clause

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151018/discussion-between-ian-h-and-bui-quang-huy).