# Should object cross links by an event be broken in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question about `cross links` in `.Net`.

As I know we should break up a cross link between objects if we want they are released by `GC`. So, sometimes there is a situation when I have an `object` with link to another `object` and that `object` has back link, but through an event. As i know if one object has a subscription to another, the second one has a link in its event in the target `object` property or in the `invocation` list for more than one subscription.

Must I always decouple these objects by myself(realizing `Dispose method` for example) or there is an another way for this kind of situation in `.Net` or may be .Net clean event links by itself?

Comment: No, you objects that are no longer to be used need to be unsubscribed from events in .NET.  See this questions for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843270/events-and-memory-leaks-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only when you do no longer need one of both (say *A*) you need to remove all references to *A*.

This includes any eventhandlers of event on *A*.

If *A* can be collected at the same time as the objects that refer to it, there is no reason to remove the references between these objects. Just remove all references to all of these objects from objects that need to stay 'alive' and the garbage collector will see that all these objects are no longer reachable and clear them up when needed.

Comment: If they reference each other and there are no other references they will be removed and you do not need to remove the references.

Comment: As I understand GC can't remove an object if it has at minimum one reference from another object.

Comment: If they reference each other and there are no other references they will be removed and you do not need to remove the references. - So Does it mean that GC can remove any size cycle linked objects if there are no other links on these objects except links that create a chain?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The GC checks for reachability. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx

Comment: Ok, I believe that I forgot about scope. Yes, I got you. Silly questions ) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should unsubscribe from events if you dont need to get it anymore (-= operator). In this case these kinds of links between object will be decoupled.